# When is a uniform space complete

Tags: general-topology, uniform-spaces

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_space#Completeness):

> a uniform space is called complete if every Cauchy filter converges.

1. I was wondering if the following three are equivalent in a uniform
   space:

   - every [Cauchy filter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_space#Completeness) converges,
   - every [Cauchy net](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_net) converges, and
   - every Cauchy sequence converges?

   Or, which one implies which but doesn't imply which? For example, are
   the first two equivalent, while the third is implied by but does not
   implie any of the first two?
2. How about in a metric space?

Thanks and regards!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In a metric space all three properties are equivalent.

In a uniform space every Cauchy filter converges iff every Cauchy net converges; the usual equivalence between filters and nets in arbitrary topological spaces preserves the property of being Cauchy in uniform spaces. This is strictly stronger than merely requiring Cauchy sequences to converge.

> **Example:** Let $X$ be $\omega_1$ with the order topology. $X$ is Tikhonov, so it has a compatible uniformity $\mathscr{U}$. $X$ is countably compact, so $\langle X,\mathscr{U}\rangle$ is totally bounded, but $X$ is not compact, so $\langle X,\mathscr{U}\rangle$ is not complete: a uniform space is compact iff it is complete and totally bounded. Thus, $\langle X,\mathscr{U}\rangle$ must have Cauchy filters/nets that do not converge. However, every sequence in $X$ is contained in a compact subspace of $X$, so every Cauchy *sequence* does converge.

Comment: "In a metric space all three properties are equivalent" is equivalent to Countable Choice $\hspace{1 in}$ (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_countable_choice). $\;$

Comment: +1, thanks! In a topological vector space: (1) are the three equivalent, and (2) are convergent filter, convergent net and convergent sequence equivalent?

Comment: @RickyDemer: How is it equivalent to countable choice?

Comment: @Tim: I don’t offhand see how to do it for metric spaces, but for pseudometric spaces it’s not too hard. If CC fails, one can construct a pseudometric space $X=\bigsqcup_nX_n$ that has no Cauchy sequences (so vacuously all Cauchy sequences converge!) but is such that $\mathscr{F}=\{\bigcup_{k\ge n}X_k:n\in\omega\}$ is a Cauchy filter; clearly $\mathscr{F}$ does not converge.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott: Thanks! I think you were trying to answer my question to Ricky. I was wondering in a topological vector space: (1) are the three equivalent, and (2) are convergent filter, convergent net and convergent sequence equivalent?

Comment: @Tim, a topological vector space is a uniform space in particular, so nets and filters are equivalent (for Cauchyness) and still sequences do not suffice in general

Comment: For a specific example of a topological vector space which is sequentially complete but not complete, see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/307000/about-sequentially-complete-and-complete-tvs .  (Note that an example of a uniform space which is sequentially complete but not complete does not necessarily suffice, if the counterexample is not a topological vector space, or even if it's a (topological) subspace of a t.v.s. which is not a vector subspace.)

Comment: Another counterexample I came up with today: consider $X = \mathbb{R}^\omega$ with the box topology.  This is a complete topological vector space.  However, it turns out that the set $Y$ of sequences with only finitely many zero values is sequentially closed but not closed in $X$.  Therefore, the (topological) subspace $Y$ is sequentially complete but not complete.