# About sequentially complete and complete TVS

Tags: topological-vector-spaces

Let us use $X$ to mean a topological vector space. I know that if $X$ is a complete TVS then it is sequentially complete. I know that the converse is not true, so what I need now is to construct a TVS which is sequentially complete but not complete. I tried but cant find such space. Any help is very much appreciated...

Comment: The dual of a separable and reflexive Banach space (so e.g. every $L^p$-space for $1<p<\infty$) equipped with the weak-star-topology is always not complete but sequentially complete.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [Counterexamples in Topological Vector Spaces](http://books.google.fr/books/about/Counterexamples_in_Topological_Vector_Sp.html?id=OjXvAAAAMAAJ&redir_esc=y).

Let $X= \mathbb{R}^d$ with $d> \aleph_0$ and $H$ be the subspace of $X$ consisting of all vectors with countably many non zero coordinates.

First, $H$ is not complete. Indeed, in complete topological vector spaces any closed bounded ($A$ is bounded if for any neighbohood $V$ of $0$ there exists $r>0$ such that $A \subset rV$) subset is closed, but $H$ is dense in $X$ and $H \subsetneq X$ (since $d>\aleph_0$) so you can build a sequence $(x_n)$ in $H$ converging to some $x \in X \backslash H$: the closure of $\{x_n : n \geq 0\}$ in $H$ is a closed bounded non complete subset of $H$.

Then, you can show that $H$ is sequentially complete thanks to a diagonal argument.

Another mentionned example is $\ell^1$ with its weak topology.

Comment: Thank you for citing the book (though I don't have that book).

Comment: The example is unclear. Do you mean "complete" instead of "closed" in the 2nd line of the 2nd paragraph? Also, the first part would as well apply to H = \Q in X = \R, nothing is specific to the X chosen here. The essential part is to "show that H is sequentially complete thanks to a diagonal argument". How is the sequence (x_n) you construct earlier (sequence in H converging to x in X \ H) compatible with sequential completeness of H?

Comment: For a similar example: if you give $\mathbb{R}^\omega$ the box topology, then that gives a complete t.v.s.  Then, it turns out the subspace of sequences with finite support is sequentially closed but not closed, so that subspace as a t.v.s. is sequentially complete but not complete.