# Equivalent definitions of complete uniform space

Tags: general-topology, uniform-spaces

> A uniform space $(X,\mathcal{U})$ is called complete if every Cauchy filter converges.

In [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/104773/when-is-a-uniform-space-complete) page, Brian M.Scott says that,

> In a uniform space every Cauchy filter converges iff every Cauchy net converges;

that is, uniform space $(X,\mathcal{U})$ is complete if every Cauchy net converges. I can show that if a uniform space is complete then every Cauchy net converges. My problem is proving the converse. Thanks for any ideas.

Comment: Hint: the sets in a filter naturally form a directed set. Pick an element from each one and you get a net.

Comment: The PDF [*Translating Between Nets and Filters*](http://www.math.tamu.edu/~saichu/netsfilters.pdf) by Saitulaa Naranong is excellent and covers everything that you need here (and then some). (I’m aware of one typo: $\Phi$ and $\Psi$ have been interchanged in the displayed implication at the top of page $11$.)

Comment: @BrianM.Scott: Thank you for recommending this PDF.

Comment: You’re welcome. It’s definitely one of the better handouts that I’ve found on the web.

Comment: The link posted in @BrianM.Scott's comment is not working at the moment. So I am posting at least link to [Wayback Machine](http://web.archive.org/web/*/http://www.math.tamu.edu/~saichu/netsfilters.pdf) where the version of this file from [March 8, 2013](http://web.archive.org/web/20130308175220/http://www.math.tamu.edu/~saichu/netsfilters.pdf) was saved.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $(X,\mathcal D)$ is a (diagonal) uniform space.

Every net on the set $X$ of the form $n:(D,\le)\to X$, where $(D,\le)$ is a directed set, has a corresponding filter $\mathcal F_n$ generated by the filter-base (=centered-family):
$$\lbrace \lbrace n(x)\mid x\ge d  \rbrace \mid d\in D\rbrace$$

It can be shown that

1. Any filter on $X$ is of the form $\mathcal F_n$ for some net $n$ on $X$.
2. A net $n$ on X is Cauchy in $(X,\mathcal D)$ iff the filter $\mathcal F_n$ is Cauchy in $(X,\mathcal D)$.
3. A net $n$ on X is converges to a point $a$ in $(X,\mathcal D)$ iff the filter $\mathcal F_n$ is converges to $a$ in $(X,\mathcal D)$.

Now it's clear that these propositions are equivalent:

1. Any **Cauchy** filter in $(X,\mathcal D)$ is convergent.
2. Any **Cauchy** filter in $(X,\mathcal D)$  of the form $\mathcal F_n$, where $n$ is a net on $X$, is convergent.
3. Any filter in $(X,\mathcal D)$  of the form $\mathcal F_n$, where $n$ is a **Cauchy** net on $X$, is convergent.
4. Any **Cauchy** net in $(X,\mathcal D)$ is convergent.

Comment: I want this answer be deleted.